# BigQuery Data copy between a new table & existing table

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have a BigQuery table which is collecting data from a Dataflow Pipeline.
Prior to building the Dataflow pipeline, I already had a MySQL instance with some data for all the tables.

Now I am trying to load the delta values, but I am not able to load them, as in my BigQuery table there is an extra column called ACTION, so the schemas don't match. Although I managed to get data into the new table.

How do I copy the data from the newly created table to the existing table along with ACTION column?
When I do a copy table it gives an error saying "table already exists".

Comment: Maybe adding the column "ACTION" to your MySQL table like this solves your issue: "ALTER TABLE $MYSQL_TABLE ADD ACTION $ACTION_DATA_TYPE;". You have to make sure the $ACTION_DATA_TYPE is the same than (or corresponding to) the BigQuery table.

Comment: Apart from what @asbovelw has proposed, 
The error message "table already exists" gives me the idea that you are trying to import the data with a "creating a new table" command, every time using the same name. 
So, it could be helpful to edit your question adding info about the way you are executing these commands.